# Database model for handling e commerce returns

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, scalability, datamodel

Table structures are as:

**Orders table**

---

```
order_id 
customer_id 
billing_address_id 
shipping_address_id 
payment_mode
price
shipping_price 
create_TS
update_TS
```

**Line Items Table**:

---

```
order_item_id 
order_id
item_id 
delivery_id 
status_id
store_id 
quantity 
unit_price 
shipping_price 
create_TS  
update_TS
```

An order from a customer can contain items from different merchants.
Every item in the order sits in the line items table with a reference to **order id** in the **orders** table.

My question is how to handle the returns?
should returns be a separate order item ? or should the status of the order item only be changed to return related statuses?

I ask this because, if it's a return we get info from the customer on the reasons for return, we might want to track return orders for analytics etc.

what's the best way to model or incorporate to handle return orders

UPDATE:

I have a tie up with a logisitcs vendor to whom I submit a request on every regular order , return order and order cancellation.

**Bookings Table**:

---

```
booking_id
order_item_id
booking_status (this is the vendor defined status)
delivery_partner_id (if we have more than one logistics partner)
is_return_order (a flag to identify if this booking is for returns)
create_ts
update_ts
```

If I have a separate returns table, how should this table be modified to hold both returns and regular orders. Currently the link is the order_item_id from lineitems table. How do I tie back a booking with the return_id?
how do I have the

Answer (score 1):

I would create an extra table where you can save information about returns like so (with references to your description above):

```
    return_id
    order_id
    (order_item_id) depending on if you need that specific information
    return_reason_id (when you have predefined reasons)
    customer_comment (when the customer has to say something 
    return_comment (if your returns department wants to add some info)
    create_TS
```

and if you get some goods back you set either the order_item or the order in the status "returned"

since the returns are no real order items i would not want to write them in there... you should use other tables for this purpose.